# What is the best approach to solve $ 4y^3 y''=16 y^4 -1$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this DE: $$ 4y^3 y''=16 y^4 -1$$
I really would not bother asking if Wolfram alpha had not exceeded comp. time and not shown me step-by-step solution.

Comment: is it $y^3$ or $(y')^3$?

Comment: it is $y^3$, not $(y')^3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach.

1. Move the $y$ terms to one side and the $y''$ terms to the other.
   $$
   y'' = 4y - \frac{1}{4y^3}.
   $$
2. Multiply by $y'$ and use the identity $d/dx(y'^2)=2y'y''$.
   $$
   \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(y'^2)=y'y'' = \Big(4y-\frac{1}{4y^3}\Big)y'.
   $$
3. Integrate
   $$
   y'^2 = 4y^2 + \frac{1}{4y^2} + C.
   $$
4. Put all the $y$ and $y'$ terms on one side.
   $$
   dx = \frac{dy}{\sqrt{4y^2 + \frac{1}{4y^2} + C}}.
   $$
5. Integrate.
   $$
   x = \int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{4y^2 + \frac{1}{4y^2} + C}}.
   $$
   Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you explain in detail 3rd step? Isn't integral of right side $\frac{1}{8 y^2}+2 y^2$?

Comment: Yeah! You're right. I fixed it.

Comment: Isn't there still a mistake? Didn't you lost constant $\frac{1}{2}$ in third step?

Comment: I think it's all fixed now. Do you see any more mistakes?

Comment: Ok, it seems fine, but unfortunately, this integral appears be impossible to evaluate in terms of elementary functions. Do you have any other solutions to problem, where it could be solved using only real calculus?

Comment: That's true. I don't think there will be an easier way to solve it, but at the very least [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%284y%5E2%2B1%2F%284y%5E2%29%2BC%29dy) can compute the integral.